# ScrollView in Relative layout not working, its effecting the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want a scroll view in my activity layout. I tried in many ways, but not getting success. The last two buttons are getting overlapped. I want to add more buttons in active layout. Please give me some suggestions to get rid from this problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Bconfiguration"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bconfiguration"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bconfiguration"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Bquestions"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bquestions"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bquestions"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Bscenario"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bscenario"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bscenario"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing where you added scrollview, i thinnk you may tried adding scrollview inside relativelayout and tried to add multiple button where it is not possible because scrollview contains only single direct child try below code and you will get an idea

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Bconfiguration"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bconfiguration"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bconfiguration"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Bquestions"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bquestions"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bquestions"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Bscenario"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Bscenario"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Bscenario"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#fff" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: also checkout your ids where you trying to positioning i think that not exists

Comment: @akarsh if it helped you then you can accept this answer or let me know

Comment: I tried this, but the last two buttons are overlapping. the scrollview is still not working.

Comment: can you share your complete layout which you tried?

Comment: welcome.. glad to know it worked and also hope you understood the scrollview behaviour